# Ruby refactoring issue

Tags: ruby, refactoring

Let's say I have an `@array = [1 ,2 ,3]`
I want to create three blocks of each number of the array with the rest like this :

```
@array.each do |first|
  (@array - [first]).each do |second|
    (@array - [first] - [second]) do |third|
      #do something
```

So each block iterates through the entire array except the element that's being used by the preceding block. But this is kind of smelly and repetitive, because for each block I need to delete the preceding elements , what is the best way to refactor these blocks?

Thanks

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Give an expected output.

Comment: Max answered me, looks like it' clear what I am asking to some people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminology for that is a *permutation*. Ruby has a [built-in](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-permutation) method for doing so:

```
@array.permutation(3) do |first, second, third|
  # do something
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much Max, this is what I am looking for. Will accept once I can